# Angular template binding with Observable async pipe issue

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6, rxjs-observables

**Note** I have created a simplified version of this question at [Template binding with function return Observable and async pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61772610/template-binding-with-function-return-observable-and-async-pipe)

Template:

```html
<div *ngIf="entity?.ext.insuredDetails.insuredType$() | async as insuredType">
 {{insuredType}}
</div>
```

`insuredType$` definition:

```js
@NeedsElement(sp(115621),ap(116215))
insuredType$(): Observable<string> {
  return empty();
}
```

`NeedsElement` decorator:

```js
export function NeedsElement(...mappings: NeedsElementMapping[]) {
  if (mappings.length === 0) {
    throw new Error('needs mapping expected');
  }

  let lookup = new Map<ProductId, number>();
  mappings.forEach((mapping) => {
    lookup.set(mapping.productId, mapping.elementId);
  });

  return (target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) => {
    descriptor.value = function (...args: any[]) {
      Logger.info("bbbbb");
      let entity = UcEntityStoreContext.currentEntity;
      let productId = entity['productId'];
      if (!productId) {
        throw new Error(`Cannot get product Id from host entity: ${entity.ucId}`);
      }
      let elementId: number = lookup.get(entity['productId']);
      if (!elementId) {
        throw new Error(`Cannot locate needs element ID by productId ${productId}`);
      };
      let enitityStore = UcEntityStoreContext.current;
      let entityApi = enitityStore.apiService as QuotePolicyApiBase<any>;
      let needsDefApi = NeedsDefinitionApi.instance;

      return needsDefApi.fetchOne(productId, elementId).pipe(
        concatMap(
          nd => {
            return entityApi.fetchNeedsElementValue(entity.ucId, elementId).pipe(
              concatMap(needsVal => {
                if (!needsVal) {
                  return of("");
                }
                if (nd.lookupId) {
                  return LookupApi.instance.getByPrimaryValueId(nd.lookupId, needsVal).pipe(
                    map(res => res.primaryValue)
                  );
                } else {
                  return of(needsVal);
                }
              })
            )
          }
        )
      );
    };
  };
}
```

The problem is the the decorator is called multiple times:

[image]

And if it goes this branch:

[image]

then it keep sending requests to the backend servcie and the binding never output anything:

[image]

It looks like it will always keep trying evaluate the observable without ending if it is an async obserable, say this one:
[image]

---

**Updates 14/May/2020**

I got the answer from [Template binding with function return Observable and async pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61772610/template-binding-with-function-return-observable-and-async-pipe/61772828)

In the end I changed the Method Decorator to Property Decorator and issue fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you use things like `insuredType$() | async` it means that angular will call this function every time when change detection is happening. therefore it calls `needsDefApi.fetchOne(productId, elementId)` every time too.

To avoid it you need to mark your component `OnPush`. What is actually a lifehack to reduce amount of calls, because it will be called only in case of changed inputs or triggered outputs of the component. If it happens often - it won't help.

Or you need to restructure the decorator to return the same `Observable` on any call for the same `entity` so `entity?.ext.insuredDetails.insuredType$() === entity?.ext.insuredDetails.insuredType$()` would be true.

Not sure if it works but it should be similar to it:

```js
export function NeedsElement(...mappings: NeedsElementMapping[]) {
    if (mappings.length === 0) {
        throw new Error('needs mapping expected');
    }

    let lookup = new Map<ProductId, number>();
    mappings.forEach((mapping) => {
        lookup.set(mapping.productId, mapping.elementId);
    });

    Logger.info("bbbbb");
    let entity = UcEntityStoreContext.currentEntity;
    let productId = entity['productId'];
    if (!productId) {
        throw new Error(`Cannot get product Id from host entity: ${entity.ucId}`);
    }
    let elementId: number = lookup.get(entity['productId']);
    if (!elementId) {
        throw new Error(`Cannot locate needs element ID by productId ${productId}`);
    };
    let enitityStore = UcEntityStoreContext.current;
    let entityApi = enitityStore.apiService as QuotePolicyApiBase<any>;
    let needsDefApi = NeedsDefinitionApi.instance;

    const stream$ = needsDefApi.fetchOne(productId, elementId).pipe(
        concatMap(
            nd => {
                return entityApi.fetchNeedsElementValue(entity.ucId, elementId).pipe(
                    concatMap(needsVal => {
                        if (!needsVal) {
                            return of("");
                        }
                        if (nd.lookupId) {
                            return LookupApi.instance.getByPrimaryValueId(nd.lookupId, needsVal).pipe(
                                map(res => res.primaryValue)
                            );
                        } else {
                            return of(needsVal);
                        }
                    })
                )
            }
        )
    );

    return (target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) => {
        descriptor.value = function (...args: any[]) {
            return stream$; // <- returns the same stream every time.
        };
    };
}
```

Comment: I got the answer from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61772610/template-binding-with-function-return-observable-and-async-pipe/61772828

Comment: why did you not close / delete this one then?

Comment: this one got more context

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer from [Template binding with function return Observable and async pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61772610/template-binding-with-function-return-observable-and-async-pipe/61772828)

The solution is to use Property Decorator instead of Method Decorator, so the insuredType$ is now:

```js
@NeedsElement(sp(115623),ap(116215))
readonly insuredType$: Observable<any>;
```

And the decorator is now

```js
export function NeedsElement(...mappings: NeedsElementMapping[]) {
  ...
  const observable = of('').pipe(switchMap(() => {
    ...
  })
  return (target: any, propertyKey: string) => {
    const getter = () => {
      return observable;
    };
    Object.defineProperty(target, propertyKey, {
      get: getter,
      enumerable: true,
      configurable: true,
    });
  };
}
```

**Note** it **MUST** define the observable outside of the returning function, otherwise it will still fall into the endless loop, say the following code won't work:

```js
export function NeedsElement(...mappings: NeedsElementMapping[]) {
  ...
  return (target: any, propertyKey: string) => {
    const getter = () => {
      return of('').pipe(switchMap(() => {
        ...
      });
    };
    Object.defineProperty(target, propertyKey, {
      get: getter,
      enumerable: true,
      configurable: true,
    });
  };
}
```